How do I get my custom build of Emacs to use the distribution's startup?
I'm running the Debian 12 distribution of Linux.  I have installed the emacs package (version 28.2) and several add-on packages (elpa and otherwise).  When I run that installation of emacs, it all works great - all of the various modes defined by the add-on packages (e.g. go-mode, markdown-mode, etc.) all just work.
But I have compiled a private build of the latest Emacs (29.4), installed to /usr/local/package/emacs, with its bin directory contents symlinked to /usr/local/bin to put them on my PATH.
But when I run my installation, I don't get all of the add-on packages that the Debian installation has.  I need to explicitly load each one in my .emacs file.
Is there a (hopefully simple) way I can get my installation to run the same startup scripts that Debian's installation runs?

It's all driven by the load-path variable.  Emacs's default is based on the prefix used when compiling and installing it:

PREFIX/share/emacs/VERSION/lisp
PREFIX/share/emacs/VERSION/site-lisp
PREFIX/share/emacs/site-lisp

It then auto-adds subdirectories found below them with bundled subdirs.el scripts.
It appears that Debian adds (at compile time) /etc/emacs to the list as well.
My custom build, installed to /usr/local/package/emacs/ defaults to a set of directories relative to that installation.  And adding new directories in my .emacs file is too late, because the initial load path (including all the subdirectory expansion) has already happened.
Workaround
Without rebuilding the app, I was able to fix (work around?) this by defining an EMACSLOADPATH variable, to prepend key directories to the load path:
EMACSLOADPATH=/etc/emacs/:/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp:/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp:

The trailing colon represents the compiled in default load path, so I don't need to attempt to duplicate the compiled-in load path.
See also: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/General-Variables.html
Better fix
There is a --enable-locallisppath parameter passed to configure which will build-in the site-specific LISP paths (defaults to PREFIX/share/emacs/VERSION/site-lisp and PREFIX/share/emacs/site-lisp)
So I can add the following to the configure command to get the behavior I require:
--enable-locallisppath=/etc/emacs:/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lsip:/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp
This doesn't include any version-specific site-lisp directories, nor does it include the site-lisp directories created by the make install process, but that's fine because I've never put anything in there anyway.
